# Is the net charge in the interior of a conductor zero even when the total net charge (including the surface charges) is positive?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

In the textbook Matter & Interactions by Chabay and Sherwood (chapter 14.6), they say

> ...any excess charges on a piece of metal, or any conductor, are
> always found on an outer or inner surface. This makes intuitive sense,
> since any excess charges will repel each other and will end up as far
> apart as possible -- on the surface of the conductor. Any multiatom
> region in the interior of a conductor has a net charge of zero.

This makes sense to me for a case where there is a net negative charge:

1. The lattice of positive ions stays fixed.
2. The sea of mobile electrons tries to get as far apart as possible, leading to electrons collecting on the surface of the material.
3. This leads to a situation where the interior is neutral but the surfaces are negative.

But it doesn't make sense to me for a situation where there is a net positive charge. In a net positive situation, I would think it would work like this:

1. The lattice of positive ions stays fixed.
2. The sea of mobile electrons would spread out evenly through the whole object because this would be the furthest they could get from one another.
3. This results in the interior being net positive, just like the surface. The interior is not neutral, unlike what it says in the Matter & Interactions quote.

Where am I going wrong in my thinking? Or am I misunderstanding the textbook?

Note: This question may seem like a duplicate of [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55119/how-does-positive-charge-spread-out-in-conductors), but the answers for that question do not answer my question.